# Dynamically changing sheet name to a value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I already found the below VBA which works, but it pulls the value of a cell within the sheet that I'm trying to change the name of, however, what I'm looking for is to reference a cell in a master sheet or a specific sheet lets say Sheet1, what needs to change in the VBA below to pull A1 from Sheet1 instead of the active sheet?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Target = Range("A1")
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Target, 31)
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Thanks alot,
Lin

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
Dim sheetname As String
sheetname = "xxxxxxx"
Dim mastersheetname as String
mastersheetname = "yyyyyyy"
Sheets(sheetname).Name = Sheets(mastersheetname).Range("A1").Value
```

You would be better off using named cells to avoid hardcoding cell addresses such as A1